# (wp-login redirect problem) What's wrong with the .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Firstly, I'd like to tell that I've solved my problem but I do not understand the root cause. The problem was about my wordpress keeps redirecting to /wp-login.php after try to access dashboard. I solved it by deleting the **.htaccess** file. After the file deleted, I found the error thrown that

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access /wp-login.php on this server

Therefore, I created a new **.htaccess** file and added the below code in the file,

```html
<Files wp-login.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from all
</Files>
```

Baam! My problem was solved! I can access to my lovely dashboard !

But I do not understand what is wrong with the previous **.htaccess** file. It worked normally until one day.

This is my old **.htaccess** file

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I spent 5-6 to solve my problem without knowing the reason. It keeps disturbing my head. If anyone know why the old **.htaccess** file caused the redirect problem, please share me (us) knowledge.

Finally, I hope my wasted time and this post can help people in the feature.

Answer (score 0):

I would first check for a bad php.ini or .user.ini file.  Some plugins may use these instead of .htaccess to configure your site.  It could be that you have a security plugin that disabled the default login page by this method.

A less likely option that might still be the case is to see if a change was made higher-up the chain, like you may have a .htaccess file in your user folder above your public-http folder. Again, this is much less likely, but some security professionals consider hiding the wp-login page "best practice", so perhaps someone did this "for you".

A malware scan may also be worth a pass. If you have an infected plugin, someone may be redirecting you by other means.